# odoo add validation for double field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9

I have this odoo py

```
class CrmProject(models.Model):
_name='crm.project'
customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner','Customer')
project_product_id = fields.Many2one('crm.project.product','Project Product')
```

how to validate and show a warning when the customer_id and project_product_id are inputted together with the same value as the one in the crm.project database? so it must be checked with the database first then show warning if it have the same value with the one in customer_id AND project_product_id input.
For example:

```
Database table crm.project
customer_id = 1
project_product_id = 2
```

Will create warning ONLY if input:

```
customer_id = 1
project_product_id = 2
```

Beside that no warning will be create

I have tried this but no warning created (update 25-04-2021)

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('crm.project')
    res = super(CrmProject,self).create(vals)
    # Add code here
    #res= super(CrmProject,self).create(vals)
    customer_id = vals.get('crm.project.customer_id')
    project_product_id = vals.get('crm.project.project_product_id')
    get_customer_id = self.env['crm.project'].search([('customer_id','=',customer_id)])
    get_project_product_id = self.env['crm.project'].search([('project_product_id','=',project_product_id)])
    if get_customer_id and get_project_product_id:
        raise UserError(_('The project has already been set before'))
    else:
        return res
```

Any help will be grateful

Comment: Can you get into more detail and add an example? Both mentioned fields have different models/relations behind it, how can they ever be the same value?

Comment: I have made some update

Comment: Ah some typical constraints. Now the question is understandable.

Comment: sorry I explained it wrong before. I've updated it again.

Comment: yes okay, still a classical constraint. if there already is a "project" with the same customer and project product show a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create constraint in your db with :

```
create unique index name_your_constraint
on crm_project (customer_id, project_product_id);
```

Comment: could you please explain it more, maybe by example?